# Headlines in social media/metadata

Tags: metadata

all,

Just started a new job at a publication and inherited EE, as well as social media accounts.

When I post content to FB/Twitter, though, what would normally be the headline field simply pulls in the name of the publication. I assume there's a really easy fix to this, but just don't know what on the backend would solve the problem.

Let me know when you can and thanks. dave.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as an easy fix ;-)
If you want control over what is shown on fb/twitter/G+ etc you are best off serving these sites data in a form they easily can understand. This means using the Open Graph protocol, twitter card data and general microdata formats. Google them for indepth explanations.
Basically, if you set your browsertitle and meta description from the contents of an entry, you can use those same fields to power Open Graph/ twitter cards.
Say you have

```
<title>{my_entry_title}</title>
```

You can easilly serve facebook an appropriate title for sharing by adding

```
<meta property=”og:title” content=”{my_entry_title}” />
```

Facebook will pick up that title.

Good starter for this kind of stuff is https://blog.kissmetrics.com/open-graph-meta-tags/